# Expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-28 path $.result

Tags: android, json, retrofit

My codes was working yesterday but today has not worked.
Error:
**Expected-begin-array-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-28 path $.result **

Mycodes and Classes:

postman result:
[image]

my retrofit:
[image]

my codes and classes:
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

several times change my codes but nothing result!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I created a fake api for myself on https://run.mocky.io/

[Here is my api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icfnn.png)

[Your interface will look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imOL6.png)

[Your MultiPlatformResponse Model will look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJmtt.png)

[Your MultiPlatformResult Model will look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk5PS.png)

[Your MultiPlatformBanner Model will look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jYVl.png)

[Your MultiPlatformAvatar Model will look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73b3n.png)

```
//retrofit implementation
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

//Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using `GsonConverterFactory` in the Retrofit to convert the API response from JSON to an object?

Comment: no  use GsonConverterFactory

Comment: I think you need to add this in your retrofit so that it can convert the response from the API to the object model you specified. Can I see how you configure your retrofit?

Comment: im sorry for my pervious reply , i use GsonConverterFactory

Comment: if (retrofit==null){
            OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

Comment: I see. The error message is saying that the result object is a string instead of an array. You might want to check if your API is still returning the same response that you posted or it has changed.

Comment: my API has not changed and worked correctly!